# TodayWidget openURL triggers multiple times application:openURL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, google-tag-manager

i wrote a simple today extension with a Tableview.
On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` i open my app with:

`[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];`

This works good in most cases.
But sometimes (mostly when the app is not running in the background) the app crashes.
The url scheme is not new to my app and has worked good so far.

I found that in these cases `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` will be triggered multiple times.

Did somebody have the same Problem, or can observe the same behaviour?

Comment: I am also getting strange crashes when opening the app from the Today Extension, in particular if the app is not running at the time.  I'll try to test and see if these methods you mention are called multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced this and it turns out to be an issue with iOS 8 and Google Tag Manager.

Having worked this through with an Apple Engineer via a Technical Support Incident, the latest information is that the problem occurs when your app is terminated, then opened from the widget, and Google Tag Manager initialises, via a call to its method:

```
self.container = [future get];
```

On Google's '[getting started](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/)' page, they suggest putting this code in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

However, putting the code here apparently spins the UIKit run loop, which means that in your `AppDelegate` you will see both of these methods being called twice in quick succession:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
```

If the app is backgrounded as opposed to terminated, this behaviour is not observed.

It's still TBC whether this is a bug in iOS 8 or Google Tag Manager but, in the meantime, you would be well advised to remove your GTM initialisation code from the AppDelegate and do it somewhere else in your app instead.

Comment: Thanks at least know i know i'm not the only one with the problem

Comment: Bug report filed, lets hope they fix it soon

Comment: @PeterSchumacher - I'm working this one through with Apple Technical Support.  From my stack traces, it looks like the second calls to these methods might be being triggered by Google Tag Manager - are you using Google Tag Manager in your app too?

Comment: Yes, i'm using it too. Do you have any more information on why or when it does that?

Comment: Yes Peter.  I have updated my answer.  You need to remove it from your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method if possible.

Comment: What about checking using some kind of boolean? will that work? I have the same issue but I would like to keep my Google Tag Manager in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: It's unlikely to help much - you'll still get some issues as the run loop spins.  You really don't have much choice but to either move it, or wait for either GTM or UIKit to change.  The last I heard from a contact at GTM, they're aware of the issue but recommending you replace the synchronous call to `[future get]` with the asynchronous code that uses a notifier instead.